# Is the writing of the proof ok?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> **Problem.** Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$. Prove that, $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L\iff\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0 +}f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=L$$

---

**My Solution.**

Let us assume that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$. Then by definition, $$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists M\in \mathbb{R}^{+})(x\ge M\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon)$$which holds iff, $$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists M\in \mathbb{R}^{+})\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\in\left(0,\dfrac{1}{M}\right)\implies \left|f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-L\right|<\varepsilon\right)$$

---

Is the writing of the proof ok?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. It would be better to set $\delta=\frac{1}{M},$ but it's fine :-)

Comment: @Rick: I posted this because when I showed this to a friend of mine he said that I should justify my writing "which holds iff..". Do I really need to justify it? If so, how?

Comment: But note that $\Bbb{R}^{+}$ sometimes denotes the set of all reals $\geq 0$; in this case, the symbol $\Bbb{R}^{++}$ denotes the set of all reals $> 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is perfectly correct, and there is nothing else to justify. A more rigorous way would be

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty }f(x)=L$,
$$\exists M>0: x>M\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon.$$
Let $\delta=\frac{1}{M}$. Then, if $y=\frac{1}{x}$,
$$0<y<\delta\implies x>M\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\implies \left|f\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)-L\right|<\varepsilon.$$

The converse goes in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to visualize this fact is by noticing that $\displaystyle \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)=L$ iff the function $f$ can be extended to a continuous function $\overline{f}:(0,\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which evaluates $f(\infty)=L$. Now, taking the continuous functions

$$g: (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$$
$$x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$$

and

$$\overline{g}: [0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty]$$
$$x \mapsto \frac{1}{x},$$

we see that $f \circ g$ can be extended to a continuous function $\tilde{f} \circ \tilde{g}: [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. By a similar reason as before, we then have that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=L$. The converse is similar.